# Thread safety of ::new in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I am certain that, in practice, use of `::new` is thread-safe. My question is what part of the standard provides that guarantee, if any? Is this a convention? Is this something where the standard gives implementations a lot of latitude (like the relatively loose constraints about what size each data type is) to support a wide variety of hardware?

I'm hoping that there's just a line in the C++11 standard somewhere that explicitly specifies "implementations of `::new` must be thread-safe".

I'd also love to see some standardese about the thread-safety of operator new overloads. I imagine that they would also need to be *required* to be thread-safe, but these functions also do not fall under the blanket guarantee that const => thread safe (in C++11).

Thanks!

Comment: Why would the standard make guarantees _to you_ that _your_ `operator new` overload is thread-safe? Your program, your problems.

Comment: @MSalters - For the same reason that it makes const => thread-safe. Because without ensuring that guarantee in your code too, you cannot interact with the standard library safely. Can you shoot yourself in the foot? Yes, like just about anything in C++... but that's hardly the point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is *implicitly* guaranteed by the C++11 standard. If it were not, then usage of the operator new or new expression might cause a data race, and that would not be allowed by the standard. For reference, see *§17.6.5.9 Data race avoidance* and also

**18.6.1.4 Data races [new.delete.dataraces]**

"The library versions of operator new and operator delete, user replacement versions of global operator new and operator delete, and the C standard library functions calloc, malloc, realloc, and free shall not introduce data races (1.10) as a result of concurrent calls from different threads. Calls to these functions that allocate or deallocate a particular unit of storage shall occur in a single total order, and each such deallocation call shall happen before the next allocation (if any) in this order."

Your own overrides or your own replacements for the global operators *should* fulfill this requirement as well.

See also this [proposal N3664 "Clarifying Memory Allocation"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html), which puts more emphasis on that matter.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not outright require that `new` be thread-safe.  Some implementations explicitly support building C++ code in single-threaded mode, where the C standard library, including `malloc()` may not be thread-safe.  The platforms most of us use every day do offer thread-safe allocation, of course.

Even if your platform provides a thread-safe `new`, you still need to be wary if you use any libraries which implement their own `operator new`, or if you do so yourself.  It's certainly possible to write a `new` which works only in a single thread--maybe even intentionally!