# Does a thread_local std::list give up the allocated memory on calling clear?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, std, stdlist

What happens when we call clear on a variable of type `std::list` which is also marked `thread_local`? Does it give up the allocated memory?

In my scenario I have a `thread_local` list which I populate in one iteration and clear by the end of the iteration. Is the `thread_local` not very useful in such a case as we give up the memory by the end of the iteration (and have to allocate memory again in the next iteration)?

Comment: "*In my scenario I have a thread_local list which I populate in one iteration and clear by the end of the iteration.*" Why does that need to be thread-local? Presumably, that's a stack variable, so why is it thread-local?

Comment: Are you sure you need thread_local list?

Comment: Good points. I might not need it as thread_local

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The marking of a variable as `thread_local` has no effect - AFAIK - on its behavior when allocating memory. So you should get the same behavior w.r.t. de-allocation on `clear()` with a non-qualified list, a thread-local list, a static list etc.

Also, note that `std::list` with the standard allocator allocates space for its nodes on the heap - the single, process-wide heap (ses also the paragraph quoted from the standard in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26378187/1593077) about this point), and there's nothing thread-local about those allocations themselves. It's just the who-list-level data members (e.g. the pointer to the first node) that's thread-local.

<sub>PS - I'm not sure the standard actually mandates that any memory be freed on calling `clear()` - but it definitely allows for it, in that the time complexity of this method can be linear.</sub>